# Facebook Unity5

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I need to link my unity app with Facebook,  my game pulls data from a website, will it be possible to put it on facebook? Is there a way to also save the game status via facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can link your app with Facebook. Have a look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity) at the SDK Facebook provides. Also have a look at this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial#overview) they provide. Think it has some mention of dealing with game status' via Facebook. Also this [script](https://github.com/fbsamples/friendsmash-unity/blob/master/friendsmash_advanced/Assets/Scripts/GameStateManager.cs#L126) shows an example of saving a score around line 126.

Comment: Do you know of a way to save data to a database and retrieve the saved data, like the score,level,category . I've tried playerprefs and serialization , both have worked, but my lecturer wants something more complex. We have the game on a website and pulls word from a database, but would it save the difficulty level?

Comment: Well playerprefs is more so used to save settings like key bindings, audio volume, etc. Because they can be removed by the player, I don't think you really want the player to be able to just delete their high scores. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SQLite) for saving data to a DB. It should give you an idea how to achieve something for your game. Oh and also an alternative to prefs and a DB would be to use local files and read them in. You could of course make it save the difficulty.

Comment: how would i go about doing that, I am fairly new to unity

Comment: Well when you create your DB table you can define anything it anyway you want. I don't know what you're looking to keep track of within your game but I'll assume it's difficulty and score. So you would create a DB table, with a column for difficulty and score. The player hits new, sets difficulty, finishes a level and then we'd want to save to the DB to save this information. Let's say the player hits continue, we'd call our script that reads from the DB which would pull back the last score and difficulty, setting them in unity then loading the level. Have a look at the tutorial in the comment

Comment: If you're still confused on the DB stuff have a look at these links, [1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html) and [2](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tutorial-how-to-integrate-sqlite-in-c.192282/)